# Не переведена волшебная ссылка [Tour] (с большой буквы)

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация

В комментариях `[tour]` с маленькой буквы превращается в русское `тур`, а `[Tour]` с большой буквы - в английское `Tour` вместо русского `Тур`.

---

On Stack Overflow in Russian if one uses the `[tour]` magic link in a comment staring from the lowercase "t" the link transforms to a `тур` string. On the other hand if one uses the `[Tour]` magic link (starts from the capital "T") it transforms to `Tour`, but it should have been `Тур` instead.

Comment: `[tour]` = [tour]. `[Tour] ` = [Tour].

Comment: Спасибо за напоминание! Думал, проблема уже решена. Еще раз уточнил у ответственных.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky [Tour] Хейердал. Уже снег пошел, а баг всё тут :)

Comment: [TOUR] [tOUR] [toUR] [touR] вона чо ... можно регистрами играть.

Comment: @alexolut, архивация 4 символов в 3 не удалась?))

Comment: @Qwertiy я думаю, тут бага, не учитывающая регистр. Надо бы другие волшебные ссылки проверить.

Comment: Завёл, вероятно, [связанный баг](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300071/339911) на MSE.